# Visual studio not showing unity's methods

Tags: visual-studio

When i opened a c# project from Unity into vs and wanted to type `OnTriggerEnter` vs didn't show the intellisense for it, infact it was not showing intellisense for all Unity methods.
Please tell how to fix this.

Comment: you should download an extension through extensions manger.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the extension Visual Studio Intellicode. Go to Entensions -> Manage Extensions. Go to installed, if it isn't there go to online and search for it and install it